# Format DataGrid Column as User is Typing

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` where on of the columns is a simple `DataGridTextColumn`. What I would like to do is as the user is typing into the row in the `DataGrid`, only allow them to enter a specific format, in this case `dd/MM/yyyy`. I shall enter the `/ /` for them, then they have to type in a date that fits this format.

This is my `DataGridColumn`;

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Width="*"/>
```

Is there a way to format the `Column` as the user is typing?

Comment: The editing in a DATAGrid is poor.  I usually recommend creating another form for entering information and then copy the 2nd form inputs into the DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in [`MaskedTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in WPF. However, you can use `MaskedTextBox` or `DateTimePicker` from **Extended WPF Toolkit**.

I would like to show a [DateTimePicker](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker) from Extended WPF Toolkit and `MaskedTextBox`.
[image]

**Update:**

Sure, you can add `DateTimePicker` to `DataGrid`

At first, download [Extended WPF ToolKit through Nuget.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit/)

Then, create pseudonym in `xmlns` to use the `WPF Extended Toolkit` library:

```
<Window
...
xmlns:wpfTool="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
   <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>        
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding IdPerson}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>                                
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>                           
                            <wpfTool:DateTimePicker Value="{Binding MyDate}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                    
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>                
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

and model class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int IdPerson { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime FirstDate { get; set; }
}
```

**OR:**

Just use `MaskedTextBox` with `Mask="00-00-0000"` from `WPF Extended Toolkit`. For example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding IdPerson}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>                                
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>                                 
             <wpfTool:MaskedTextBox Mask="00-00-0000" Text="{Binding CheckDateTime}"/>                           
          </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                    
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>                
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and then parse `CheckDateTime` by `DateTime.ParseExact(...);`

Comment: Can it be used inside a DataGrid?